# retina macbook pro keyboard cleaning solution

Tags: keyboard, macbook-pro, macos

I'm curious what solution people use for cleaning off laptop keyboard keys.
I've been told that you shouldn't use isopropyl alcohol, because it can wear away at the plastic (I've seen evidence of this, although I'm not sure that it was due to alcohol).

Can anyone steer me in the right direction?
I know there are other threads for this, but none of them quite match the exact model of my computer, and I know that the keys have been composed of various materials throughout the years...

Comment: Consider what is the main contaminant of your keyboard? yes.. it is the grease from your fingers. So using soap is the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a rMBP. I use [Clorox Disinfecting Wipes](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0009PCOF0) on the keys and a Q-tip soaked with [99% isopropyl alcohol](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001B5JT8C) to clean in between the keys. I would not use anything less than 91%. Here is a photo of my keyboard:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I use a slightly damp micro-fibre cloth... actually, that's what I use to clean most things these days, from kitchen to bathroom to car...